# Web .NET service throwing 404 code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, model-view-controller

I had a working code that I was debugging but after doing some refactoring inside the method, my unit test gets back an 404 and can figure out why.

Code from POST Method

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string ReturnXmlDocument(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        try
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
            Stream s = new MemoryStream();

            doc.Save(s);
            s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(PictureModelList));
            using (XmlReader newReader = XmlReader.Create(s))
            {
                PictureModelList obj = (PictureModelList)mySerializer.Deserialize(newReader);
                string path = @"C:\testfolderforservice\";

                foreach (var item in obj.PictureList)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(string.Format("{0}{1}", path, item.FileName), item.Data);
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ;
        }

        return "Success";
    }

}
```

Code from Unit Test

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        List<PictureModel> lPM = new List<PictureModel>();
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\source", "*.jpg");

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            PictureModel pm = new PictureModel();
            pm.FileName = Path.GetFileName(file);
            pm.Data = File.ReadAllBytes(file);
            lPM.Add(pm);
        }

        PictureModelList pmL = new PictureModelList();
        pmL.PictureList = lPM;

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(pmL.GetType());

        StringWriter sq = new StringWriter();
        serializer.Serialize(sq, pmL);

        sq.Close();

        string xmlData = sq.ToString();

        var content = new StringContent(xmlData, Encoding.Unicode, "text/xml");

        var client = new HttpClient();

        var result = client.PostAsync("http://localhost/api/Home/ReturnXmlDocument", content).Result;
    }
```

Like I said before, only did some refactoring  inside the POST method and executing the unit test the PostAsync method came back with a 404 code.

I was able do debug the POST method by attaching to process, or but maybe I'm doing everything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with getting rid of the empty catch. The way you have it, "success" will be returned even after an exception. Empty catch blocks are never a good idea.

Also the ReadAsStringAsync is questionable since you aren't await-ing it, the response may not have a value in it yet when you read it.

How are you determining the test is failing? I don't see any Asserts on the result.

Are there any ExceptionFilters in effect?

Perhaps posting the "before" refactor code that was previously working may provide additional clues.